# Docker: Setting Timezone in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, timezone

In `docker-compose.yml` I have two options to define the Timezone inside a Container:

**Using Environment Variables**

```
environment:
  TZ: "America/Los_Angeles"
```

**Or mounting a local volume from the Host:**

```
volumes:
  - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
```

My question now is, what is best practice here? As far as I understand correctly, both procedures lead to the same goal. The advantage I see with the first version is that I can define different time zones for different Docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. Most of the docker-compose self-hosted application deployment from GitHub, uses "TZ=Asia/Muscat" method for docker applications to be deployed in servers.

The environmental variables approach is beneficial if you are deploying the docker container in a server from different region. For example, you want to deploy an docker container for yourself(imagine you live in central/east Europe, the application you deploy needs Berlin timezone (Europe/Berlin), but you have a server avialable in Europe-west(example: Madrid). You would go for this approach.

Docker-compose Uptime-kuma example.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    uptime-kuma:
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '3001:3001'
        environment:
            - PUID=1000
            - PGID=1000
            - TZ=Europe/Berlin
        volumes:
            - '/path/to/host/uptime/:/app/data'
        container_name: uptime-kuma
        image: 'louislam/uptime-kuma:latest'
```

The host volumes method allows you to ensure that the container uses the exact same timezone configuration as the host pc/server. This also can be useful if the container doesn't support the "TZ" timezone.

Usually, suggested to deploy in environment variables as it provides the flexibility to serve the container you are trying to deploy in the time zone you want. Again it depends on the use case.